# Error (CANNOT GET/) when deploying with node.js on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, backend

I'm currently at the deployment stage of my code on Heroku. I've specified different routes on my server.js which I named script.js.

This is my backend code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');
const register = require('./controllers/register');
const signin = require('./controllers/signin');
const profile = require('./controllers/profile');
const image = require('./controllers/image');

const db = knex ({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true,
  }
});

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";
app.use(express.static(distDir));

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.send('it is working!')
});

// ROUTE 1
// Dependency injection
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {signin.handleSignin(req, res, db, bcrypt) })

// ROUTE 2
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt) })

// ROUTE 3
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {profile.handleProfile(req, res, db) });

// ROUTE 4
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {image.handleImage(req, res, db) });
app.post('/imageurl', (req, res) => {image.handleApiCall(req, res) });


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()=> {
    console.log(`app is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

When i ran `heroku open` on cmd, it displyed "it is working" like I wanted it to.
however for other routes it shows CANNOT GET/ error.
I've also run `heroku logs --tail` on cmd and found no obvious error.
The front-end application is working correctly
Kindly help me

this is the register route. I suspect i've made an error i can't seem to find

```
const handleRegister = (req, res, db, bcrypt) => {
  const { email, name, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !name || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
  }
  const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
    db.transaction(trx => {
      trx.insert({
        hash: hash,
        email: email
      })
      .into('login')
      .returning('email')
      .then(loginEmail => {
        return trx('users')
          .returning('*')
          .insert({
            email: loginEmail[0],
            name: name,
            joined: new Date()
          })
          .then(user => {
            res.json(user[0]);
          })
      })
      .then(trx.commit)
      .catch(trx.rollback)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register'))
}

module.exports = {
  handleRegister: handleRegister
};
```

Comment: you have only two GET routes in your app. if you try to access anything other than these two as GET requests, it will show  CANNOT GET/ error.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I tried for the profile/:id and got a response. Please any suggestion for how to go about handling the post requests?

Comment: You can use [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test your requests.

Comment: Thank you very much Kammar, I'd do that

Comment: Kammar, I've added the code for the register route above, When i tried on postman using the post method, it returned unable to register which is the reply to an error but i'm not seeing errors in the heroku logs

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sachin Kammar for helping. I found out the problem was with the ssl certificates
I ran this in my script.js
`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` 
and everything worked perfectly. Please note the code above has security issues but for development purposes it suffices.